# Unable to connect to mysql on Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, remote-access, azure

I created a virtual machine on Windows Azure. In that I installed MySQL. Every thing works fine on the server. I am not able to connect to MySQL remotely.

Steps performed:

1. Installed MySQL
2. Created user on it and give it access from % (all ips)
3. Allowed connection to MySQL (3306) in windows firewall
4. Created an endpoint in Windows Azure portal.

When I connect using xyz.cloudapp.net , I get an error with code (10060) .

I am not able to connect to any other service as well.

Answer (score 1):

Either you will you use wha codingoutloud suggests or there is an option to purchase a public IP (paid service tho) and assign it to the Instance running MySQL, but i would not go that way only for a single port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

In the portal, the VM has a tab for ENDPOINTS. In there you need to expose an endpoint through which you can manage MySQL. The ENDPOINTS tab allows you to configure an arbitrary external port # which you can map to whatever the usual port is for managing MySQL internally (on the VM) - though you can make them both the same port if you prefer.

Since Azure is secure by default, if you don't do this step, Azure will not open any ports for such access.